# Saving and Restoring RecyclerView when switch between activity

Tags: android

I have HomeActivity contain recyclerView show data load from Firebase, but when click items and back HomeActivity then app reload data from Firebase. I want holder data when back HomeActivity (list data put into CustomAdapter).

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing the Homeactivity again via `startActivity()`, or calling `finish()` or `onDestroy()` in the Homeactivity
There are 3 options:

1. You need to save the data in a database with the help of `SqliteOpenHelper`. Display data by extracting it from the database instead of Firebase
2. Save data in cache. Cached data can be re-accessed without storing it. Cache duration and size would have to be determined by you.
3. Store data in a shared preference which can be accessed when the activity is opened again.

When using any of the three methods, you need to specify when the app should connect with firbase to get new data. You can set up a gcm notification to tell the app new data is available or schedule a time after which the app will try to check if new data is available and try to download it.

HomeActivity will by default be in the activityStack, so if a backpress is pressed in NextActivity, HomeActivity will open as such.

`savedInstanceState` works for configuration change (i.e. rotation etc.). You will need to override `OnSaveInstanceState`, to prevent `OnCreate` to from removing all the data. But if you are accessing the Homeactivity again via `startActivity()`, or calling `finish()` or `onDestroy()` inside HomeActivity then this data is lost.

Comment: Can I using savedInstanceState for saving data ?

Comment: Are you just trying to do a backpress or doing a startActivity? If you do a startactivity then you will have to use from the above options else, on backpress the activity state is anyway stored unless destoryed

Comment: If I using any of the three methods , I mush check app should connect with firebase to get new data and re-update  data ? Here, I want when app started or pull refresh I will get data from Firebase and show HomeActivity?

Comment: @suku how about if the activity is recreated due to orientation changes? the best solution for this would be onSaveInstance and restoring data onCreate.

Comment: @k0sh, I think I'll reframe the answer to remove the confusion